# Can I use Magento Community to learn how to create Magento Enterprise Themes?

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme, frontend, magento-community

Pretty simple question, I hope it's not too absurd for those with knowledge!

I am a frontend developer, I work for a company (that for reasons I won't bore you with, do not have direct access to the Magento frontend at this moment in time but that will change) that uses Magento (2) Enterprise. In my own time I'd like to develop the skills to be proficient in working on Magento in terms of frontend and themes.

If I was to install and work with the Community version would it be a total waste of time or would I be able to grasp some of the basics, quirks and concepts so when I am faced with Enterprise I'm not caught in the headlights.

If not, what is the best way to get hands on practice with Magento themes for Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you'll be fine with the community edition, the only differences I'm aware of are mainly additional features such as Varnish, gift options, wishlist etc. They don't change how you work with the front-end very much.